# Reading Data from Magento Table and converting it to XML

Tags: magento-1.8, php, xml

I'm able to read the the product name and description using the following queries on the magento database table using PHP.

```
SELECT value FROM mg_catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 71 AND entity_id = $entityid

SELECT value FROM mg_catalog_product_entity_text WHERE attribute_id = 72 AND entity_id = $entityid
```

The data extracts successfully and it displays content when I just echo. But when i Convert the extracted data to xml im getting the error. If I do not provide the $entityid variable then the last record is extracted and successfully converts to xml. If i provide a static value in place of $entityid i'm getting that particular value, in XML but when i provide the variable name it throws an error. PFB the error image

[image]

XML code that creates the node. This code is placed within a while loop

```
        $xml_entityid = $xml->createElement( "productid", $entityid );
        $xml_productname = $xml->createElement( "productname" , $productname);
        $xml_descrp = $xml->createElement( "description" , $descriptionn );

        $xml_product->appendChild( $xml_entityid );
        $xml_product->appendChild( $xml_productname );
        $xml_product->appendChild( $xml_descrp );

        $xml_products->appendChild( $xml_product );
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use for converting to xml?

Comment: XML Code added to the question

Comment: See my asnwer. It's an alternative approach. It generates an XML but as a string. If you need it as an xml object just call this after generating it: `$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml)`

Answer (score 8):

here is a built in way to export a product as xml.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($entityId);
$xml = $product->toXml();
```

This will generate an xml with all the product attributes.
If you want to have only the name and description, do this:

```
 $xml = $product->toXml(array('name', 'description'));
```

This will generate something like :

```
<item>
    <name>Name here</name>
    <description>Description here</description>
</item>
```

If you want to change the tag `item` into something else, call it like this:

```
 $xml = $product->toXml(array('name', 'description'), 'product');
```

If you want the xml header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` call it like this:

```
 $xml = $product->toXml(array('name', 'description'), 'product', true);
```

and because the description can contain special chars it may be a good idea to add `<![CDATA[]]>` around the values. For that supply a 4th parameter `true`:

```
 $xml = $product->toXml(array('name', 'description'), 'product', true, true);
```

**[EDIT]**

The method `toXml` I used above is defined in `Varien_Object` class. If you are trying to achieve this outside Magento, you can add that class to your project and use it to generate xmls.
After retrieving the data from the db, just create an instance of `Varien_Object` and set the name and description.

```
$obj = new Varien_Object();
$obj->setName(your name from the db);
$obj->setDescription(your description from the db);

$xml = $obj->toXml(array('name', 'description'), 'product', true, true);

//$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml); //if you need it as an object
```

Comment: The code is not written within Magento, due to this we will have to use only PHP and its basic library. Is there a work around?

Comment: @Dilipkumar4813. See my update to the answer. I think this is a good and fast alternative to using basic xml php library.